# How can I reliably check whether one Windows process is the parent of another in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm working on a function which gets me the PID of the parent process for a given PID. The prototype of the function is

```
DWORD getParentPid( DWORD pid );
```

To do so, I'm using the [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function (and related functions) to get the [`PROCESSENTRY32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure for my given PID `pid`. I can then use the `th32ParentProcessId` field of the structure to get the PID of the process which created my given process.

However, since the parent process might have been destroyed already (and it's PID might have been reused by Windows), I'm using the [`GetProcessTimes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get the creation times of the supposed parent and the child process and then compare those using [`CompareFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If `CompareFileTime` returns `-1`, I know that the process with the parent ID was created before my child process, so it's indeed the parent. Otherwise, it's apparently a re-used ID - and the parent PID is invalid (it doesn't reference the original parent anymore).

The issue with this is that it very much relies on a strictly monotonous system clock and the granularity of `GetProcessTimes`. I did experience cases in which `CompareFileTime` returned `0` (which means "equal time") even though the process being considered were indeed in a parent-child relationship. I could change my check so that a `CompareFileTime` result value `<= 0` would be considered to indicate a parent, but then I would break the (theoretical) case where a parent created a child process, then the parent was destroyed, and then Windows re-used the PID - all within 100ns (which is the resolution of `GetProcessTimes`).

I wonder - is there a different, more reliably, mechanism to verify that some process is indeed the parent of another process in C++?

**Edit:** I need this function in order to determine all child processes (this means including grand-child processes). The [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) lets me iterate over all processes but I need to look at the parent PID of each of them to tell whether it's a child of my process at hand.

Comment: Not really. But why do you need this? If you don't even know whether the parent process is still running, what would you do with it even if it could be reliably identified? Sounds like a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: @jalf: I edited my question to give some more context.

Comment: that's not context. You're just explaining the next step of whatever it is you're trying to do. So if I ask you "why do you need to determine all child processes"...? ;) If you don't even know whether the parent process is still running, it's hard to see what determining parents/children would achieve.

Comment: @jalf: I'm trying to show a process tree (or, optionally, a subset of the process tree) in the GUI. If this is not context either, this is part of an application for watching runaway processes. If this is not enough context, it's for a customer who wants to debug running processes (which tend to run away, in which case he may or may not want to kill a whole tree of processes, kinda like Process Explorer).

Comment: There is no way of telling if a process was created by another specific process. The "th32ParentProcessId" field you refer to is in fact called "InheritedFromUniqueProcessId" in the kernel EPROCESS structure, and it indicates the process from which attributes were inherited. Although most of the time it does indicate which process created the child process, this is NOT guaranteed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686701(v=vs.85).aspx

Shows calling CreateToolhelp32Snapshot with a parameter of 0 for the processId and it uses the option TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS which says it captures all processes. Then, once you've got the snapshot, as in the sample you can walk the processes as they existed in the snapshot. The parent id's should be valid within the snapshot because you're looking at the state of all the processes as they existed in the single moment when the snapshot was taken. You don't have to bother with your process start time comparison stuff.

Comment: There's no guarantee that the parent process existed at the time the snapshot was taken. It could have terminated an hour earlier.

Comment: This was my first attempt, before I improved the detection using `GetProcessTimes` as written in my question. What jalf writes is exactly the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Ok. An interesting discussion if you haven't seen it: http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Blog/Killing-Trees-the-Windows-way

Comment: @Scott: That's a really interesting article, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Accepting this answer since there's a comment in the link Scott posted which suggests to use WMI to listen for process creation/destruction events and maintaining a mapping. This sounds like it could actually work reliably.

Answer (score 1):

If the process(es) have been created whilst your app is running, you could just iterate over it repeatedly over time and catch PID re-use.