# Is my application runs from inside Visual Studio vs. by executing an EXE file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

As I often test my binaries inside/outside Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, I want to control the behavior of my code in C/C++ console projects.

- One for code for when I run .exe from within Visual Studio in **Release** mode.
- Another when I just click my .exe from Explorer.

**What flag or function should I use** to know if my **.exe** was started from inside Visual Studio or not.

What I would like to achive is the:

```
#if !_RELEASE
    system("pause"); // prevents auto shutdown of my .exe in Explorer
                     // double click
#endif
```

where _RELEASE is some kind of trait that triggers code in Studio launches,
but not visible in Explorer double click.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191430/discussion-on-question-by-startup-maker-is-my-application-runs-from-inside-visua).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It not exactly solution, but:

**Raymond Chen**(Microsoft winapi guru*) is most close in spirit to the problem I facing, helping me detect in what mode or circumstances I run my console session.

[How can I tell whether my console program was launched from Explorer or from a command prompt?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160125-00/?p=92922)

```
printf("this process = %d\n", GetCurrentProcessId());
DWORD count = GetConsoleProcessList(nullptr, 0);
if (count == 1) {
    printf("I'm the last one!\n");
    Sleep(2000);
}
else {
    printf("I'm not the last one! %d\n", count);
}
```

Comment: As problem still open, I gladly see any solution in CODE form.
NOT in isoteric and retoric. Remember i asking for good and elegant code solution.

Answer (score 1):

> What flag or function should I use to know if my process was startded from inside Visual Studio or not.

1. You shouldn't do such behavior control from inside your program code. That's bad design, and clutters your program code with decisions that should be left on the caller.
   I'd recommend if you need different behaviors of your program (e.g. running in background or with visible GUI), this should be controlled with e.g. configuration files or command line parameters.
   You can do that for both, Visual Studio settings to specify cmd line parameters, or using a different configuration file, or even a combination of both.
2. As you seem to insist for a solution of your idea how to fiddle with this in the best way:
   You can use the WINAPI functions to iterate through your parent process IDs and check if one of these is matching the *"Visual Studio*" module.
   Here's a Q&A which links to the technique:

   - [**How can I reliably check whether one Windows process is the parent of another in C++?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593003/how-can-i-reliably-check-whether-one-windows-process-is-the-parent-of-another-in)

Comment: 1. It still not the answer, 2. using parent process ID is very complex prone to errors and just too massive and messy solution, I not trying to build whole operating system around my exe

Comment: @startup.maker 1. Solves your problem. _2. is massive, error prone and messy_ But I can't see another simpler way. Thus I recommended you to do 1.

Comment: @startup.maker At this point, the solution that you want probably doesn't exist, and I doubt that you'll get much more from this question. I suggest that you simply work with the solutions that we've given you.

Comment: @startup.maker You didn't even propose a trial in code, so why are you expecting solutions in code?